# Use Facebook API to see which friends are going to an event

Tags: facebook-graph-api

If I have an access token for a Facebook user, is there a way to see which of their friends are going to an event? I'd like there to be a way to filter `https://graph.facebook.com/<event_id>/attending/?access_token=<a_t>` to only return friends of the user whose `access_token` is provided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you also include the `friends_events` permission with your token you can get the list of friends attending.  I just verified in the Graph API Explorer that this permission and `{event id}/attending` will work like a charm.

Another way would be to use FQL, but it will be messier.

Comment: For clarification: do I need to include the permission on the request (and if so, is there a link for how I do that?), or do I need to ask for that permission when I get the token? In the latter case, how do I choose whether I want to do filter or not?

Comment: You will be asking the user for this permission at the time they authorize your app. Not at the time of the request.

Comment: If you ask `friends_events` and `rsvp_event` - `{event id}/attending` will returns all participants list